# How to test whether a Platform Event Trigger throws an unhandled exception

Tags: apex, unit-test, platform-event

Since platform event triggers are run asynchronously, an error in processing them doesn't cause the test method to fail by itself.

So, how would I write a test that under certain circumstances, my PE trigger should do nothing and not cause an unhandled exception?

The specific scenario I want to test is when the data my platform event is supposed to process has been removed between the platform event firing and the trigger running. It does a query to make sure the data is still available, so it ought to work, but I want a test in place to prove it.

Here's what I tried so far (in the last part of my test):

```
Test.getEventBus().deliver();
Id triggerId = [SELECT Id FROM ApexTrigger WHERE Name = 'MyTriggerName'].Id;
EventBusSubscriber eventBusSubscriber = [SELECT Retries, Status FROM EventBusSubscriber WHERE ExternalId = :((String)triggerId).substring(0, 15)];
System.assertEquals('Running', eventBusSubscriber.Status);
System.assertEquals(0, eventBusSubscriber.Retries);
```

If I force my trigger to throw an exception, this passes, even though I can see from the debug log that my trigger did throw the exception.

Is there any way to check this?